# `test` on appended line using `stdin`

Tags: bash

A CSV log file is appended every 10 seconds by a line with the format: "`date`,`int`,`int`,`int`".

I'm looking for a way to run a script (or a single command) on this file to rise an alert when one of the `int` goes below a defined value.

So far I wanted to test with one `int` using `tail -f logfile | cut -d "," -f 2` but I don't know how to use `stdin` with `test`.

Any suggestion, even not using `tail`, is welcome. The alert risen up can be an `echo`, that's OK to test.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean `stdin` and `test`.

Comment: @Jdamian: What the OP is asking for is how to use `test` to test the output from the `cut` command passed via stdin through the pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[klashxx's helpful `awk`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37453339/45375) works, but makes it somewhat awkward to invoke shell commands in response to values falling below the threshold (you could use the `system()` function from within `awk`).

Here's a solution that addresses this problem by using a Bash loop with `read` for parsing each line instead, which makes it easy to invoke arbitrary shell commands in response to alerts:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

limit=800  # define threshold value
while IFS=, read dt i1 i2 i3; do
  if (( i1 < limit )); then
    echo "i1 below limit"  # invoke any shell command here
  elif (( i2 < limit )); then
    echo "i2 below limit"
  elif (( i3 < limit )); then
    echo "i3 below limit"
  else
    echo "OK"
  fi
done < <(tail -n 1 -f logfile)
```

If you wanted to (though I don't recommend it), you could cram this into a one-liner, optionally with a pipeline:

```
tail -n 1 -f logfile | { limit=800; while IFS=, read dt i1 i2 i3; do if (( i1 < limit )); then echo "i1 below limit"; elif (( i2 < limit )); then echo "i2 below limit"; elif (( i3 < limit )); then echo "i3 below limit"; else echo "OK"; fi done; }
```

Comment: Best solution if you need more than a *simply* `echo`

Comment: Indeed @klashxx, my question was not that clear I guess. I would like to know the reason of the space between the two `<`.

Comment: @Auzias: The first `<` is an input redirection, which is needed, because `read` can only read from stdin, not directly from files. The second `<` is part of a [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) (`<(...)`), which, simply put, creates a transient temporary file containing the enclosed command's output and returns that file's path. The space between the two `<` instances is needed, because `<<(...)` would cause the `<<` to be interpreted as the start of a [here-document](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument), which would result in a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

A few assumptions here, but this can be close to your expected result:

```
tail -f logfile |awk -F\, -v limit=5 '$2<limit{print "alert"}'
```

Of course your `limit`var should be set to your needs and `{print "alert"}`could be replace by any action.

To *handle* more than one column:

```
tail -f market.log |awk -F\, -v limit=800 '$2<limit{print "alert 1"}$3<limit{print "alert 2"}'
```

Comment: It perfectly works! I would like to request an edit. How to perform the test on other variable? `tail -f market.log |awk -F\, -v limit=800 '$2<limit{print "alert 1";$3<limit{print "alert 2"}'` is not syntaxically correct. Mind to help me a bit more? :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be the complete script :

```
#!/bin/bash 
while true
do
  awk -v threshold=$1 'BEGIN{
  FS=","
  }
  END{ 
  # threshold value passed as arg1 is stored in awk variable threshold                 
  if( $2 < threshold){ #checking if value goes below threshold
    print "Beep Beep"
  }
  }' /path/to/your/csv_file
  sleep 10s # Remember CSV log file is appended every 10 seconds
done
```

Save the script as, say,threshold_checker and 
run it like

```
threshold_checker threshold_value
```

Comment: I rather use `tail -f` so the tests are performed ASAP. Also I'ld rather use `while read line; do; command ; done <file` than use a `while true`. Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: Not only is `tail -f` more timely, it also more efficient in that it only reports the lines that were _appended_, whereas this solution reads the _entire file_ in each loop iteration.

Comment: well I agree. :-)  tail is optimal for the job. I have seached awk documentation to see if the newer versions of awk is smart enough not to process unwanted records and I didn't find an evidence suggesting this. So  I'm perfectly inline with your opinion. tail should be used when case permits.